# No rule to make target `doc/View_Client_Admin_Guide-en.pdf', needed by `all-am'. Stop

Tags: view, makefile, debian, vmware

I am attempting to build vmware-view-open-client-4.5.0-297975+dfsg, ./configure worked fine, but now when I'm trying to make or make install in that directory, I'm getting:

```
Found cached translation database
Merging translations into vmware-view.desktop.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `doc/View_Client_Admin_Guide-en.pdf', needed by `all-am'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/vmware-view-open-client-4.5.0-297975+dfsg'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/vmware-view-open-client-4.5.0-297975+dfsg'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

as an error.  Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to fix this so I can proceed with the build?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the debian package just patches that bit of the makefile out. =)

You should probably just do the same. Though I imagine that's what got you into the other error you ran into in which case you should probably just modify the resulting Makefile directly instead of the Makefile.am/Makefile.in since those trigger the autotools rebuild.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had edited the Makefile.am file to see if I could bypass the error.  See edited error message above.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  This is the section that I commented out previously:

Comment: The autotools construct output `Makefile`s from input `Makefile.am`/`Makefile.in` files. When the autotools detect that the .am or .in files have changed it rebuilds the corresponding Makefile. I assumed you had changed one of the .am/.in files. If you changed the Makefile itself that's a different story and you might need to try changing the .in file or installing automake like it suggested.

Comment: Couldn't find AutoMake-1.0 via aptitude.  However, the change I made in Makefile.am was

I'm not sure I follow you.  This is the section that I commented out previously:

@INTLTOOL_DESKTOP_RULE@

ALL =
all: $(ALL)

I commented that out trying to bypass it since ALL wasn't defined.

Comment: Actually, when I go into Makefile.in, it says it was generated by automake 1.0, so that's already installed.

Comment: 1.10 not 1.0 and the .in files are part of the tarball. That line doesn't look like anything even remotely related to your problem. The doc/Makefile.inc file has a line near the top where it mentions the pdf in question. The debian patches remove (or empty I forget) that line. You should be able to do the same in that file and run ./configure again.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you.  Now if only I can figure out how to maximize my screen refresh rate...